# Remove "/public" from file path in Laravel when linking public directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel of 5.7.25 version.

1. I have a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `/storage/app/public`.
2. I'm storing files in `/storage/app/public/place-images` directory.
3. I keep the path of stored file in table `files` which keeps all stored files. The file path would be `public/images/some_hash.jpg`.

Now I made a file resource, which is used when I'm getting files from my API. The file path retured from api equals `public/images/some_hash.jpg`. But instead I need it to be `images/some_hash.jpg`. However, in the table I prefer to keep real path of the file related to the storage folder. After all, I can keep files in AWS or somewhere else.

As far as I understand `storage` is the root of my `disk`. The `$file->store()` method includes `public` part of the file path.

I end up doing something like this:

```
    // This is ImageResource file, Image model has File relation. One Image has one File

    // TODO: Dirty hack
    $path = $this->file->path; // This equals 'public/place-images/hash.jpg'

    // Removing 'public' part
    $charIndex = strpos($path, '/');
    $path = substr($path, $charIndex + 1);

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'original_name' => $this->file->original_name,
         url' => asset('storage/' . $path) // now we have /storage/place-images/some_hash.jpg which is correct
    ];
```

Is there anyway to avoid this dirty hack? I think I'm missing something obvious

Comment: while saving in the database why don't you remove public folder

Comment: Because I think that all file paths should be relative to storage/app folder. Like, some files might not be public, other might be. What if I store other files in storage/app/non-public for example. Some will have /public others won't (in database)

Comment: Hmm then tht is your only option then

Answer (score 0):

1. `storage` is not the root of your disk. You can set the root for a disk in `config\filesystems.php`.
2. Default root for the `public` disk defined in `config/filesystems.php` is `/storage/app/public` so just store `place-images/hash.jpg` without public.
3. If you want to keep files from different disks in one table just add a field with a disk name to this table.